# Set HTTPS-only for secure pages - No data received error

Tags: https, secure

We only need to set HTTPS for secure pages:

Account pages, login pages, checkout and shopping cart pages.

We are using it as in the following image.

[image]

Is everything fine in the image? Because sometimes we will get a no-data-received error on the site.

[image]

Comment: How you configure in this page Account pages, Login pages, checkout and shopping cart pages post that code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start Secure Base URL with `https://......com`.

And set *Use Secure URLs in Frontend* to ***No***.

Comment: but we found this eror : "This web page has a redirect loop" after setting https://tt.collagekingapp.com for "Secure Base url" . is this configuration is  the reason for "No Data recieved Error"

Comment: Please  check server configuration.Most of case there are hosting provide issue

Comment: did problem resovled?

Comment: no, still "No data recieved error is there "

Comment: In order check https? and write txt on magento root dir and run this fil from https & http both,

Comment: [link1](https://test.collagekingapp.com/robots.txt) and [link2](http://test.collagekingapp.com/robots.txt)

Comment: u have check that ur site is perfectly working on https

Comment: yes, but than "No data error recieved " is some other issue , right ?